# I'm getting this error while installing PyAudion on a mac

Tags: python, pyaudio

Here is the error I'm getting while installing PyAudio to my mac.
I did install portaudio but still getting this error.
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0XEA.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42fsG.png)
Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have the necessary wheel (a .whl file to do so), now, Go [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio), after that, install a suitable wheel eg: The suitable wheel for me is PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, as I have python 3.9(cp39) and it is a 64 bit installation(amd64). After installing it in a directory (say, C:/docs), got to cmd and write

```
cd C:/docs
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

In future, if you ever encounter this error (failed to build the wheel for xyz module), you can just install the windows binary files from the aforementioned link.